# Baking metallic, roughness and ambient occlusion map into 1 texture map

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine, texture-baking

Is that possible to bake roughness, metallic and ambient occlusion into 1 texture map in blender so I can use it easily in unreal engine, as substance painter do?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Bake all textures into 3 files and then combine them in Gimp, Krita, Photoshop or Blender's compositor:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer it was quite helpful. I searched using composite to mix these maps but unfortunately I couldn't find anything helpful, could you please help me and give me a tip on how to do that?

Comment: This process is called channel-packing

Answer (score 2):

###### It depends what are you using.

If you got 3 values in shading editor, then **YES**
You can bake all 3 into one, but must use emit node, or just directly connect packed values as color to output.

I use ucupaint addon, so I paint what I want: color, metal, roughenss. Then I add some modifiers to each layer. This node "Ucupaint Node" just lets me reroute all that values into emit node.

[image]
Just change bake type to emit and you should have channels packed.

[image]

##### Downside

Downside of this is that you will not use any blender shaders, like Principled BDSF,  it may benefit some textures, but I don't know it yet. I wait for somebody to explain to me some technical aspects in this question if using *Emit* approach is ok.
[Which is correct way of baking roughness map. Emit node or Principle BDSF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314177/which-is-correct-way-of-baking-roughness-map-emit-node-or-principle-bdsf)