# Which is correct way of baking roughness map. Emit node or Principle BDSF

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

So I was baking textures and I wonder why results are slighlty different and which approach is actually correct. I use cycles.

##### blender docs

I tried to find some explaination on docs [BSDF page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html).

So BSDF can mix a lot of shaders, but then it should look the same. Maybe? Most parts have same roughness value, but there are differences, since I don't understand why it happens I can't decide which are valid.

[image: BDSF]

Baked using BSDF:

[image: Shader bake]

[image: Roughness BDSF texture]

Baked using emit:

[image: Emit bake]

[image: emit texture]

##### My opinion

Personally I think baking using emit is correct, because what I paint in blender with values between 0-1 it is baked unchanged to textures. But maybe im wrong, maybe shader is doing some clever stuff that I want in my textures.

Comment: For the rare times I bake in blender, I bake using emission too. Even by doing so, the outup is not always correct